# CMSMS module Availability with CGCalendar

Tags: content-management-system, module

***CMSMS module QUESTION ***

Hi all,

I have asked this question on the CMSMS forum but as of yet have not received any responses, so hopefully someone here can help!

I am using the 'Availability' module in conjuction with 'CGCalendar' which is great, but in stead of buttons to go the next and previous months (powered by Ajax), I need a drop down select box to choose a new month/year. I thought I had figured this out by refreshing the page with jQuery passing thorugh new values for month and year, but although the reservations change as required, the number of days in the month and the start date are the same as the initial number.

You can view a test page here:

http://aonachmor.cahilldesigns.com/test

Hopefully this makes sense, I know it is a bit specific but you guys are professionals and someone out there must know how to fix this!

Thanks